# Elastic Search Query For Making Range For 2 Mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi i want make query that x greater than min_rent and x least than max_rent.
Here the mappings.

```
'mappings' => [
                    'project_listing_v1' => [
                        'properties' => [
                            'location' => [
                                'type' => 'geo_point'

                            ],
                            'min_rent'=>[
                                'type'=>'short',
                            ],
                            'max_rent'=>[
                                'type'=>'short',
                            ]
                        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bool query with a must clause as such:

```
GET project_listing_v1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
       {
          "range": {
            "min_rent": {
              "gt": x
            }
          }
       },
       {
          "range": {
            "max_rent": {
              "lt": x
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: You have to replace 'x' in the query with the actual value.

More on bool queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html